# Does the argmin operator commute with the sum operator?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima

Under what conditions on $f$ is the following true?

$$\arg\min_{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d\in\mathbb{R}^d}\sum_{i=1}^d f(x,\alpha_i)=\{ \arg\min_{\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}} f(x,\alpha_i)\}_{i=1}^d=\{\hat\alpha_1,\ldots\hat\alpha_d\}$$

But now that I think of it, is it not trivially true if $f$ is a scalar function, defined as piecewise and disjoint on its domain?

Comment: It is hard to make sense of the equality you are proposing. argmin is the argument for which a function attains minimum, so (even assuming optimistically for a moment that the optimum is unique) the left-hand of your equation is a point in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and the right-hand is a point in $\mathbb{R}$. What is $\alpha$ in relation to $a$? Please think through what exactly it is you want.

Comment: @Michal Adamaszek I presume the OP means"min" (minimum objective value) instead of "arg min".

Comment: @Mark L. Stone - Apologies, I do mean arg min, as opposed to arg.

Comment: @Michal Adamaszek You are correct what I wrote was so poorly notated it didn't make sense. What I want is to answer the following question: under what conditions are the arg min values of $d$ summands equal to the $d$ summands of arg min values? It seems to me that this must be true for some scalar function $f$, trivially, but I am worried that there may be some condition upon $f$ that I haven't thought of.

Comment: @knightontable the left side is a d-tupel of real numbers, the right side is a real number. This cannot be equal

Comment: @miracle173 you are correct, sorry I should have thought longer before posting. I will edit my original post to correct.

Comment: Maybe $${\arg\,\min}_{(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d)\in\mathbb{R}^d}\sum_{i=1}^d f(x,\alpha_i)=(\arg\min_{\alpha_1\in\mathbb{R}} f(x,\alpha_1),\ldots,\arg\min_{\alpha_d\in\mathbb{R}} f(x,\alpha_d))$$